# How to draw on bitmap using another bitmap as mask?

Tags: android, mask, porter-duff

I want to *draw* on a bitmap using another bitmap as mask. The mask is a black bitmap with a transparent object in it. I want this transparent part to be filled with an arbitrary color and added to my original image. How can this be done?

[image]

### +

[image]

### + blue color =

[image]

Comment: do you have any choice/possibility to change the masks? e.g. using white object on transparent background? then you could use some kind of multiply between mask and blue color

Comment: in either case, this guide could help you to do what you'd like http://kevindion.com/2011/01/android-bitmap-blending-color-channels/

Comment: Yes, I believe I could change the masks. The link provided is **great**! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to change the masks as described by @Christian. Then, the wanted result could easily be produced:

```
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0.0f, 0.0f, paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting this to an ImageView, a quick way is to set the background to the gradient drawable, and a blue 'T' with a transparent background as the ImageView's source. Not fancy, but fast and simple!