# Image mask by another image or color using c#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap

I looking for solution just like in the above question just in c#

[question about android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835435/how-to-draw-on-bitmap-using-another-bitmap-as-mask)

I know how to do this with color, but I need to do this with image too.

Here is my code for color replacement:

```
Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(img);
for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
    {
       if (bit.GetPixel(x, y).A != 0)
       {
          bit.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
       }
    }
}
bit.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a picture `picA` and a mask `picM`. Some pixels in `picM` are transparent. You want to manipulate `picA` by changing (the color of) the pixels at the exact coordinates where `picM` has transparent pixels, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best answer but it's working.

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("OriginalImagePath"));
Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(img);

System.Drawing.Image mask = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("MaskImagePath"));
Bitmap bitMask = new Bitmap(mask);

for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
    {
       if (bit.GetPixel(x, y).A != 0)
       {
            bit.SetPixel(x, y, bitMask.GetPixel(x, y));
            //bit.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
       }
    }
}
```

If the mask image not in same size as the original, we need to crop it before we can replace the pixels,
of course.